# Nested hypervisor CentOS 7.3 guest install hang black screen

Tags: hyper-v, centos7, installation, windows-server-2016, hypervisor

Trying to install CentOS 7.3 VM in a nested hypervisor situation.

I have a need to work with a CentOS 7.3 VM guest working within a Windows 2016 Hyper-V environment, that is a second generation VM type. Sadly, I don't have a free machine to install 2016 directly, so I am forced to go to nested virtualization within another hypervisor.

I currently have two VMware products available for nesting, with the same results. First is a Windows 7 machine with VMware Workstation 12, another is a VMware ESXi 6.5U1 (free type).

I have successfully installed a guest 2016 instance with hyper-v enabled in both VMware environments. I can successfully create a gen 1 VM guest from the CentOS 7.3 DVD ISO (so the iso file probably isn't bad). I get the same behavior in either hypervisor

I have attempted to create a gen 2 VM, with secure boot either disabled or set to the Microsoft UEFI CA. The DVD ISO appears to load, and am offered to install or test as expected. Selecting any install option proceeds to a black screen with a non-blinking cursor. 2016 taskmanager shows guest CentOS VM has captured memory and is using one core equivalent at 100%, no IO. The upper hypervisor (ESXi or Workstation) report similar CPU usage. Leaving this for several hours shows no progress. It's like it's stuck going in a loop.

I have tried some of the internet solutions regartding Hyper-V configuration, such as changing the SCSI DVD drive configuration (change SCSI ID, add a different SCSI controller, holding down the spacebar during UEFI boot, no network card) but no change in behavior.

The really bizarre part is the gen1 CentOS 7.3 VM installs and works fine in the nested environments. So, how does one get a nested CentOS 7.3 gen2 guest VM to actually not hang when booting initially during an install and not get stuck at that prompt?